# How to make the y-axis start point at the top of the image when gdal2tiles cuts and outputs the image?

Tags: leaflet, gdal, gdal2tiles.py

I am developing a web based game map display function, using Leaflet as the framework. The game map resources are self-made 9000 * 6000 png images. I use gdal2Tiles to create tiles that conform to the framework structure,

```
gdal2Tiles. py - p raster - z 3-7- w none test2. png.
```

The output directory structure meets the requirements, but there is a problem. The y-axis of gdal2Tiles starts from the bottom of the image, while the y-axis of leafet starts from the top of the screen, so the displayed image is incorrect. Is there any way to make gdal2Tiles output from the top of the image? It provides some parameters such as - s_ SRS, -- profile, but these parameters are too professional for me to understand. Is there any other good way to output images that meet the requirements.

Comment: You can probably set the geotransform (perhaps wrap it in a VRT). What does the current geotransform look like when you run gdalinfo for example? Is the y-resolution (last item) negative currently?

Comment: Pal, the Leaflet coordinates for `L.CRS.Simple` are different from the Leaflet screen/pixel coordinates. Re-read the Leaflet tutorials (specifically the `L.CRS.Simple` one) and review your assumptions.